# Does the Cauchy Schwarz inequality hold on the L1 and L infinity norm?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So i am wondering if the Cauchy Schwarz inequality holds for all p-norms, not just when p=2, which is the euclidean space.

Thank you.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is about inner product spaces. Do you mean the triangle inequality perhaps?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit more?

Comment: Do you mean something like [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)?

Comment: I am asked if the cauchy schwarz inequality holds for the following norms, ||x||_1 amd ||x||_infty, that is all.

Comment: So look at Hölder's inequality for $p=1$ and $q=\infty$, that is all.

Comment: Theorem (Hölder's inequality). Let (S, Σ, μ) be a measure space and let p, q ∈ [1, ∞] with 1/p + 1/q = 1. Then, for all measurable real- or complex-valued functions f and g on S,

‖fg‖1≤‖f‖p‖g‖q.
If, in addition, p, q ∈ (1, ∞) and f ∈ Lp(μ) and g ∈ Lq(μ), then Hölder's inequality becomes an equality iff |f |p and |g|q are linearly dependent in L1(μ), meaning that there exist real numbers α, β ≥ 0, not both of them zero, such that α|f |p = β |g|q μ-almost everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Cauchy Schwarz inequality can be generalized as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{d}
|x^\top y|\leq \|x\|\|y\|_{\star}, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R^{n}}
\end{equation}
where $\|\|_\star$ is called the dual norm. 
Since dual of $l_2$ norm is itself, using $l_2$ in above we reach to Cauchy Schwarz inequality. Since $l_1$ and $l_\infty$ are dual, we obtain:
$$|x^\top y|\leq \|x\|_1\|y\|_\infty$$

Comment: You should be a little careful when you say that $\ell^1$ and $\ell^{\infty}$ are dual.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: uh, why? As far as I can tell he is talking about the $\ell^p$ norms on the finite dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @WillieWong D'oh. Didn't see the $\in\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score -2):

Among other things, this question is easily construed as a reasonable one, about the continuity of pairings $\langle, \rangle \colon V\times V^*\to \mathbb C$. Among other true things that can be said, it is a general fact that separately continuous pairings on Frechet spaces turn out to be jointly continuous for general reasons. ... thus... what is the real question?